How do I get-install an older Emacs in Linux
For Linux I use Ubuntu and have always added Emacs from its current repository by apt-get install emacs. I have encountered a bug in the latest version and would like to install different intermediate versions to uncover when the bug was introduced in order to provide some guidance to the developers. How do I do it?

Have you checked that the bug has not been reported already? If it has not, it's easier for you and quicker for everybody to report the bug now and worry about providing more info later: the devs are going to ask for whatever info they need, but generally speaking, providing a recipe to reproduce the bug, starting with emacs -Q, should be enough.

I have reported it and the developers are struggling with the problem. If we can't fix it then I want to return to an earlier version of Emacs without changing the system. Additionally, it is generally helpful to be able to test older versions of any program to try to track down what appears to be a new problem.

Is building Emacs from source an option for you?

I'll add a "second" to @lawlist's question: if you can clone the tree from Git, you can build any version you want. However, assuming that the problem occurs only on the most recent version of Ubuntu, chances are that the problem was introduced by Ubuntu and does not occur if you run the same version of Emacs on another distro. If that is the case, then I 'd suggest that you start Emacs without loading the (Ubuntu-specific) site.el file and test for the bug. To do that, say emacs  --no-site-file.

--no-site-file has no effect.
